# Checkbox in Userform1 to display yes and no. VBA code

Tags: vba, checkbox

I have a sheet named keylist and made a userform1 for it. Simple and nothing fancy.

The options on the userform1 are Date, Key #, Aaddress, Key in (checkbox1), Key  out(checkbox2) and Comment.

I have the userform1 working and all, except the check boxes. This is what I've got:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dcc As Long
 Dim abc As Worksheet

 Set abc = Worksheets("Key List")

With abc

   dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.CheckBox1.Value
'.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value

If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then

.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = "Yes"

Else

TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox3.Text = ""

End If
End With

End Sub
```

And:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Set wsActive = ActiveSheet
LastRow = wsActive.Cells(wsActive.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

I had the code after the else checkbox1 but it wasn't really working so I deleted it. The ' in textbox4 is intentional because I was thinking of adding another field in sheet and form and then decided not to but left it in case I need it.

As I said above all works but the checkbox functionality is not working. What I'm aiming was/is that if "In" is checked in form then yes goes in on the sheet and if "In" is checked that "Out" can not be checked. Logically it won't make sense for anything to be in and out at the same time and it's one or the other at any given time. So how do I go about it and make them check boxes work?

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idnmg.png)
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iji71.png)

I tried few things and none worked. If anybody can help with the VBA code and help get checkboxes working, I'd appreciate it very much. One more thing that if add entry is clicked on userform1 and no fields are filled data is entered still. How can I stop that from happening? User must fill in the fields in order to make an entry or else if by mistake add entry is clicked and blank entry goes in the sheet, sort of blank because date is entered still.

Thanks in advance and I appreciate your help. Cheers.

Comment: Another case of failure to use F1.  In the VBA IDE putting F1 on a keyword and pressing F1 brings up the help page for that keyword.  Try it for Me.CheckBox.Value.  Secondly, change your checkboxes to radio buttons and make sure that the radio buttons are in their own group.

Comment: @Freeflow you're right. I did not go through F1 help but I'll do that now and as you suggested change the checkbox to radio button. I appreciate your help and will update once I figure it out. Cheers.

Comment: Radio buttons FTW! This is exactly what they're designed to do.

Comment: Also, if that's the entire content of `Private Sub Userform_Initilize()`, then it's a waste of code. You're setting some local variables which are immediately deleted when the code ends. `LastRow` is not going to be persisted anywhere once the `Sub` ends, nor is `wsActive`.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for your pointers, again! I appreciate your help. Yes that's all in the initialize. Shall I just delete it all?!! I just replaced checkboxes with ratiobuttons and made a frame just to make it look bit fancy lol. Not sure how to group them and all, as suggested by Freeflow but I'm working on it and hoping to figure it out. Just replacing the code in userform from checkbox to radiobutton did nothing so I've to group them and F1 lol to see. I'll give it my best effort and see how it goes. Good to see you around FreeMan. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, just delete `Userform_Initilize` it's buying you nothing. It's been a bit since I've done a form, but IIRC, you have to create the `Frame`, then drop things in it in order for them to be contained. It's not about "looking fancy" it about creating actual functionality.

Comment: Yes that what I did. I deleted the checkboxes and then made frame first and then added radio buttons in frame. Right now it looks like that group have to be made on the sheet. Trying to figure it out. Thanks again for the valuable pointer, its much appreciated!

Comment: OK I gave them same group name in userform and called it option. Nothing happens. Changed group names to In and Out since have two columns and still nothing happens. I think I configured it correctly, in my own opinion but if it was then it would work which is not the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183379/discussion-between-m-t-and-freeman).

Comment: Anybody? Still need help with this code please.

Comment: Based on these comments, seems you've changed your code and you still have an issue. Can you please update your code to show what you currently have and state (again?) which output you're not getting as desired?

Comment: @Lambik Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. I got it working but forgot to update the code here. Funny thing actually, I got it working same day but a mistake of mine really had me run in circles all day long in panic mode. I needed it on saturday so I was in desperate lol. I had the column D font in white. Yes, in white! Genius I know lol. I was banging my head that what is wrong, nothing was wrong. It was working but I couldn't see it due to the font colour! Then messed the code, then got it working then messed, I did that few times in panic that day. A simple basic mistake gosh. Contd..

Comment: I will add the code here and I changed the checkbox to radiobutton as previously suggested. It's all good now. The file is being updated right now and I will add it here as answer since it's all good. Many thanks @lambik for your intention to help, I appreciate it very much. Perhaps on something else I would need your thoughts. Cheers.

Comment: @Lambik I've update the answer which is working for me. I'm stuck again on another form which you helped me with. I'm trying my best to not post another question here, I'm really trying! I had to change/update form, I got it working but not as it should and I don't know how to configure search facility, so yes I'm lost.

Comment: just ask another question, nothingvwrong with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim dcc As Long
  Dim abc As Worksheet
  Dim Yc As Long

   Set abc = Worksheets("Key List")
   Yc = Choose(Me.OptionButton1 + 2, 4, 5)

   With abc

  dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  .Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
  .Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
  .Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
  .Cells(dcc + 1, Yc).Value = "Yes"
  '.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
  .Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value

 End With

TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox3.Text = ""
Me.OptionButton1 = 0
Me.OptionButton2 = 0

End Sub
```